# Changing display language on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, language-pack

I'm trying to change the display language of Windows 10. While I'm about to do that by following the instructions I found online, something unexpected happens. For almost all the walkthroughs on the web, there is at least an icon which indicates a display language pack is available at the preferred language selection screen, but for me there isn't.

Here is the image of what I'm seeing:

[image: Here is the image of what I'm seeing]

Here is what it actually needs to be:

[image: Here is what it actually needs to be]

So I can't install the pack as a display language. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Language Packs are not all created equal.  Some can be chosen as the language for the interface (display language) others cannot.  If you have a Single Language edition of Windows, this might also be a side-effect of that, cannot really tell since the screenshots have not be translated to English

Comment: Unsurprisingly , but for anyone wondering, "Yüklenecek dili seçin" is Turkish for "Select language to install", "Iptal" means "Cancel", "Ileri" means "Next".

Answer (score 0):

#### Install Windows 10 language pack using Windows Update

> 1. Go to *Settings* -> *Time & Language* -> *Region & language*.
> 2. Select a region, then click *Add a language*.
> 3. Choose the language you need. You may also need to choose a specific region if it is English, French, etc.
> 4. Click the language pack you just added, then click *Options* -> *Download* language pack. Here you can also download Handwriting and Speech pack.
> 5. Go back to the previous screen when the download is complete, and then click the *Set as default* button.
>
> If everything goes well, the display language should be changed after a reboot.

<sup>[**Source:**](https://www.jihosoft.com/tips/download-install-windows-10-language-pack.html)</sup>

In the search box under *Choose a language to install* search for either Spanish or Español, not Spain. Spain is a nation, not a language. Then the search results will show choices of many Spanish speaking countries instead of just Spain. The icon for the display language is the icon with a capital A on the left side of the row of 4 icons.

[image: Choose a language to install]